# I can't validate tag img

Tags: javascript

this is Augusto from Italy

when migrating from HTML to XHTML I am facing an unresolved problem

In html code I have an image (bigimg) that is at first charged via Js charged by the body onload, then other images, out of a preview series,  are being charged, thus replacing my image,

In body:

```
<body onload="...........;viewimgac('images/accessories/img01cs.jpg');...............">
```

The function is:

```
    //  the waiting image view and the main image loading is managed 
function elaboraimgac(urlimg) {
    document.getElementById('dattesa').style.filter = "alpha(opacity:"+90+")";
    document.getElementById('dattesa').style.MozOpacity = 90/100;
    document.getElementById('dattesa').style.KHTMLOpacity = 90/100;
    document.getElementById('dattesa').style.opacity = 90/100;
    MM_changeProp('dattesa','','style.visibility','visible','LAYER');      //  div is made visible through the waiting gift.
    document.getElementById('bigimgid').src = urlimg;      //  I load the image
```

The code page shows:

```
<img src="#" id="bigimgid" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" onload="finecaricimg()" alt="" />
```

the  `<img>` tag, as it is, prevents XHTML validation. I have to eliminate onload="finecaricimg()", being the function allowing view of image duly placed in the page using the image size that is available after loading.

I acted this way:

1) change  `<img` tag

```
<img src="#" id="bigimgid" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" alt="" />
```

2) I added :

```
function elaboraimgac(urlimg) {

//to Js elaboraimgac function 
//........
//........

document.getElementById('bigimgid').onload = finecaricimg();   //  the specific function is called after loading

}
```

To intercept the image loading end and recall the loading end function

Unfortunately the procedure is unsuccessful. Via alert I realized that the image size – when the loading end is charged – is zero, as if `finecaricimg()` is charged right after the .src processing and not when the image loading is over.

I tried to add:

```
document.getElementById('bigimgid').src = urlimg;alert("AAAAA");      //  load image
```

then, when the alert window appears, I wait for some seconds before clicking OK. This way the image size is correct and the image is properly placed in the page.
I am unable to understand, as the code seems the correct one.
I am therefore asking for your suggestion.

Comment: What do you think `finecaricimg()` does?

Comment: What do you think finecaricimg() does?

Comment: I mean that when the image is completely loaded I want to execute finecaricimg().....

Answer (score 2):

```
....onload = finecaricimg();
```

You just called your function *immediately* and assigned its result to `onload` (just like any other function call).

You want to assign the function itself, without calling it.

Comment: with "onload" I want to wait in executing function until the loading is finished

Answer (score 0):

I have  solved in this way:

```
var img = document.getElementById("bigimgid");
img.src = urlimg;                                                      //  carico l'immagine
img.addEventListener("load", finecaricimg);                            //  a fine caricamento richiamo la funzione specifica
```

thanks